# Play Framework: Inheritance sort by type

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

In my Application, I have 2 Classes:

```
- Group
- Model
```

and one base class `Element`.

I use the single table strategy to persist these models. `(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`. Thus a column `dtype`is created in my table.

I'm now trying to sort my pages based on this type:

```
find.where().disjunction()
                .add(Expr.ilike("name", "%" + filter + "%"))
                .orderBy("dtype asc, name asc," + sortBy + " " + order).findList()
```

But this throws an Exception, that dtype cannot be found.

How can I sort based on the type?

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, but if you have `find` method declared in your `Element` it always choose only rows with `dtype = 'Element'`, doesn't it? in such case sorting by it is unnecessary.

Comment: Well I want both classes `Group` an `Model`to appear in the search. So I use find on the base class (`Element`). But I want Objects from Group to appear before Model.

Comment: Just created a sample app with inherited tables, it's possible to use discriminator field in your finder... abyway there's some work to do :)

Comment: See here: https://github.com/biesior/TestSingleInheritance and especially here: https://github.com/biesior/TestSingleInheritance/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.java#L26

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is working great. If you post an answer I'm more than happy to accept it.

Comment: `@Column(name = "dtype", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String dtype;`
 and `@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "dtype", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample base model can look like:

```
package models.db;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "dtype", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("content")
public abstract class Content extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "dtype", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String dtype;

    public static Finder<Long, Content> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Content.class);

    public String title;
    public Date created = new Date();
    public Date modified = new Date();


}
```

Then you can extend it like:

```
package models.db;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("news")
public class News extends Content {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public static Finder<Long, News> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, News.class);

    public String newsSource;

}
```

or

```
package models.db;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("post")
public class Post extends Content {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public static Finder<Long, Post> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Post.class);

    public Date publishDate;

}
```

So you can choose all contents via:

```
List<Content> contents = Content.find.where().orderBy("dtype ASC").findList();
```

Of course these objects will have only shared fields: `id`, `dtype`, `title`, `created` and `modified`, for getting i.e. (News) `newsSource` or (Post) `publishDate` you need to get these objects with their own finders i.e. using `id` value from *general* Content query.