# How should I define database schema when using inheritance in play?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, database-migration

I have the follow classes defined:

```
abstract class Item extends Model
{
    public Double price;
}

class Shoe extends Item
{
    public String someAttr;
}

class Cloth extend Item
{
    pubic String someOtherAttr;
}
```

Then, how should I write my database migration file in Play so that the above fits in as I defined them?

Should I use one table called "items" with all the additional attributes for every subclass, or should I create a table for each subclass? If the latter one, should I create a table for the parent class as well?

Comment: You should use it the way you think fits you better http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance .

Answer (score 0):

This question returns quite often here... So I created sample available on Github: https://github.com/biesior/TestSingleInheritance

`Content` in this case is *generic* model, and others extends it.

See the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26525301/1066240) for more details.